# Angular - Bootstrap: Modal not opening from button dropdown menu

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog, ng2-bootstrap

I have three components - app, sideNav and wallForm. In the app header, I have a button that drops down the sideNav. The sideNav has an add button which opens the wallForm modal. This is an ng2-bootstrap modal. The drop down menu loads fine, but when I click on the add button, the modal loads and the screen greys out (disabled), but the modal does not show in the front. I know it has loaded because I can inspect the element in browser developer tools. I tried setting the z-index of the modal to a very high number, much higher than that of the drop down menu and that didn't help. How do I get the modal to behave as it should i.e., display on top?

Code below:

```html
<!--app.html-->
<div>
    <!-- Nav bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-color">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="nav_center">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="btn-group" *ngIf="authenticated">
                    <button type="button" class="nav-features nav-expand-button dropdown-toggle"
                            (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" *ngIf="authenticated" id="navFeaturesButton"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                        <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
                        <span>Walls</span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu sideNav">
                        <div><i class="fa fa-caret-up fa-2x"></i></div>
                        <side-nav id="sidenav"></side-nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>

        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- sidenav.html -->

<div class="nav-features-content">
    <div>

        <ul *ngIf="showContent">
            <!--<li *ngFor="let wall of walls" class="wallListItem">-->
            <li *ngFor="let wall of walls | filter:[{Title: searchTerm}]">
                <div class="themeColor"></div>
                <a [routerLink]="['/wall', wall.Id]"> {{wall.Item.Title}}</a>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal sideNav-ellipsis" ></span>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <br />
        <div class="addWall" (click) ="wfModal.showNew()" >
            +  add wall
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!--Modal dialog-->

<wall-form #wfModal></wall-form>
<!--this is the modal body-->
```

```html
<div bsModal #wallFormModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
     style="position:absolute; top:30px; right: 30px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="hide()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <span class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="panel">
                    <form #wallForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save()" class="wallForm">
                        <!-- content excluded for brevity -->
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you add the ng-app attribute on a root html tag ?

Comment: Andrei, I am not sure what you are referring to. Please elaborate? This is angular 2.

Answer (score 1):

Well I cant tell you why bootstrap drop down is causing you an issue. I also suffered from bootstrap drop down issues as well. however here is a possible work around. try using an angular plugin for your drop down, I use this one https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-dropdown.

For the modal I also use an angular2 plugin because of bootstrap issues, `ng2-modal` found here  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-modal

Here is a working plunker of the final product [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/cW9vnN0qT08ADplwnxhm?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Bean. I will try this solution and update you on the result.

Comment: any luck on this?

Comment: No Bean :( I just changed the design. The sidenav component emits and event which is caught by it's parent - app. The app loads the modal. 

I raised an issue on the ng2-bootstrap github page as well. The solution they provided didn't work for me either.